# Why can't I re-select from my listbox (EXCEL VBA)?

Tags: excel, listbox-control, vba

What I am trying to do here is to allow my user to select 1 or more project status from a dropdown list, then filter the pivot field according to the user's selection. It works, but when I try to re-select again, I can't, unless I re-run the macro. Why is this so, and how can I resolve it?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41eda600-8bf9-46c1-9eb7-f0b3ad56d78a/why-cant-i-reselect-from-my-listbox-excel-vba?forum=officesetupdeploylegacy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tied the list-boxes to the wrong macro? I see it reference to another workbook.

I suppose you should tie them to the macro in the same workbook?